# Magento1: Payment method "Zero Subtotal Checkout" not working

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, orders, payment-methods, coupon

I would like to use a coupon code that allows 100% off on a product but the store still ask for a payment method as a `Required Fields` but the fields are blank. I enabled the `Zero Subtotal Checkout` at admin but it doesn't seem to work. 
Please see the following Screenshot.
[image]
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and writing this to guide anybody who was facing the same issue.

First: I had to update the layout `[theme]/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml`

> from this:

```
    <form action="" id="co-payment-form">
      <fieldset>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

> To this:

```
    <form action="" id="co-payment-form">
      <fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Second: I had to comment out the description list, which was set to display none in the CSS `skin/frontend/[theme]/css/thme.css`

> Like this:

```
    dl.item-options > dd, dt {
    /*display:none;*/
    }
```

After that payments list options were displaying. I hope this helps someone!